# Can I get non ASCII numerals globally (without rooting my device)?

Tags: languages

I'm using 'Redmi note 7 pro'. This device has a huge language support, but unfortunately it does not handle numerals efficiently. It supports non-ASCII numerals in some places (eg. dates, phone numbers) but doesn't support them in some places (eg. Dialpad, time)

Is there any way to make this setting global (and not local)?

Is there any software which can change the UI in a way which enables unicode everywhere?

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit more? And perhaps, a specific one (in what language is the non-ASCII numerals?). Do you mean *displaying* non-ASCII (might be restricted to the font used by the app), or *inputting* non-ASCII (use 3rd-party keyboard apps)?

Comment: Ok so I have selected Marathi (an Indian language) as my system language. This language uses Devanagari script. Right now I am able to see some system apps names in Devanagari, numerals at some places, but not everywhere.